# Gcloud Instances have no Docker Hub RateLimit

Tags: docker, gcloud, digital-ocean

Recently Docker introduced rate limit for the Docker Hub: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/download-rate-limit

On my local machine and DigitalOcean I can see these in action when running:

```
TOKEN=$(curl "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:ratelimitpreview/test:pull" | jq -r .token)

curl --head -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ratelimitpreview/test/manifests/latest 2>&1 | grep RateLimit
```

I see for example:

```
RateLimit-Limit: 500;w=21600
RateLimit-Remaining: 491;w=21600
```

But this isn't the case when running this on a fresh GCP Gcloud instance. There the headers for RateLimit are not returned. Any idea why this could be?

Answer (score 1):

At least 2 alternatives:

- Google's infrastructure is (inadvertently) stripping the headers
- Docker is not (applying the limits adding the headers) to requests from Google's blocks

I suspect the latter is more probable because Docker may be concerned at unintentionally rate limiting by (shared) IPs. However, I tried an authenticated (to Docker) test too and that could have utilized my identity but to rate limit me but that did not include the headers in the response either.

If you suspect the former, you should submit a support ticket to Google and have a support engineer trace the request for you.

> **NOTE** I used a Cloud Shell VM

Comment: Answer from GCP support: I understand you notice there is rate limit when pulling image from outside of GCP but there is no rate limit when pulling from inside. For that the only explain I can find is from the same article: "Container Registry hosts a cache of the most requested Docker Hub images from Google Cloud, and GKE is configured to use this cache by default. This means that the majority of image pulls by GKE workloads should not be affected by Docker Hub’s new rate limits.". I am not sure what image you are pulling, may be that will explain your observation.

Comment: article: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/mitigating-the-impact-of-new-docker-hub-pull-request-limits)